# A question about Ščedrov's "Forcing and Classifying Topoi"

Tags: topos-theory

I'm trying to read Ščedrov's *Forcing and Classifying Topoi*, and there's a bit in 1.1 that is frequently references, but I don't quite understand its import. If I'm not missing the point, 1.1 is essentially a description of his overall method of engineering a category of sheaves to contain an object with certain properties.

There is then this paragraph:

> Additional geometric requirements (expressed through possibly infinitary disjunctions of formulae) define a Grothendieck topology on $C^{op}$ (alternatively, a geometric theory $T_2$, cf. [MR], Chapter 9). This corresponds to "cutting down" in the examples at the beginning of this section, cf. [Jo 1, §3.4.]. $[\ldots]$ The object we need is then (as a universal model of $T_2$) a subobject of (the associated sheaf of) the "diagonal" functor $G$ in $S^C$, $G$ arising from the evaluation functor by the Yoneda embedding: $$G=\sum_{c'\in C}Hom_C(c',-),$$ the generic object in $S^C$.
>
> (iv) Since $G$ is a *universal* object with the required geometric properties, it might satisfly further non-geometric requirements (e.g. preservation of cardinals in set-theoretic focing).

Why is $G$ the object of interest in Ščedrov's scheme, and what is its universal property? This appears to be the final step in his outline of his approach, but I am having a hard time understanding the motivation for the details here; but it's clearly important as he uses various forms of $G$ in later chapters.

(In case it's relevant to the reader, [MR] is Makkai & Reyes's *First Order Categorical Logic*, and [Jo 1] is Johnstone's *Topos Theory*.)

Comment: I don't know if I can really answer this question.  I can say, though, that this $G$ looks like the natural generalization of the $G$ I defined in the other answer to the case of forcing over a small category, as opposed to just over a poset (with maybe a reversal of direction conventions thrown in).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for taking a look in any case!

Comment: I note, towards possibly answering this myself at some point, that I should have recognized this $G$ as an object of generators for $S^C$. Probably if I understand what happens to such an object under sheafification by a subcanonical topology this will make more sense.